# I need help in the program by c

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int Datatype;
typedef struct singlyLinkedList
{
  Datatype data;
  struct singlyLinkedList *next; 
}node;
typedef node *linkList;

void InitNode(node *n){
    n=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data=9999;
    n->next=NULL;
}

linkList CreateListOnL(void){
    int value;
    linkList head=NULL;
    puts("if input 9999 then end");
    puts("input, please：");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    while (value!=9999)
    {
        node *p=NULL;
        InitNode(p);
        if(!p){
            puts("fail");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        p->data=value;
        p->next=head;
        head=p;

        puts("input the value, please：");
        scanf("%d",&value);
    }

    return head;
}

int main(void){
    linkList L;
    L=CreateListOnL();

    linkList head;
    node *p;

    head=L;
    p=head;

    int i=1;
    while (p->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("linked-list %dst：%d\n",i,p->data);
        i++;
    }

    printf("linked list %dst：%d\n",i,p->data);
}
```

I study the linked-link, so I white the code by C.
But I am a C language beginner,I try to run the program, but it is fail, i can't find the bug.
The program can compile and than doesn't have bug.
The compile is MinGw-w64 GCC 11.4.0 64-bit.
Help

Comment: At least one problem is that `InitNode(p);` won't change the value of `p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is in the InitNode function.

That should be:

```
void InitNode(node **n){
*n=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
(*n)->data=9999;
(*n)->next=NULL;
}
```

In this way you can work with the address of the pointer. In your version you are passing a NULL pointer to the function.
(call the function like this: InitNode(&p);)

The other problem is in the print of te linked list.
In the while loop you are not updating the pointer and you get an infinite loop.
You have to add:

```
p = p->next;
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by applying proper indentation to the source code. Also, in C it is not required and also not recommended to cast the return value of `malloc`. It is either useless or even hides errors. You should remove that cast.